# Failed to open stream: Permission denied [windows] [orchestra/testbench]

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am developing package for Laravel using XAMP on windows 10 but I can't load the routes.

```php
# Loading routes and migrations in service provider
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "routes");
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "database" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
            . "migrations");
    }
```

Error when running tests:

```php
1) Tests\Unit\CreatePostTest::test_post_require_title
ErrorException: require(H:\User\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\src\routes): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:231
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php:152
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php:152
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\src\LaravelBlogServiceProvider.php:16
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:93
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:653
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:928
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:909
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:910
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php:17
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\orchestra\testbench-core\src\Concerns\CreatesApplication.php:358
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\orchestra\testbench-core\src\Concerns\CreatesApplication.php:234
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\orchestra\testbench-core\src\TestCase.php:80
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\orchestra\testbench-core\src\Concerns\Testing.php:82
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\vendor\orchestra\testbench-core\src\TestCase.php:48
H:\Hossein\Xampp\htdocs\laravel-blog\tests\Unit\TestCase.php:12
```

you can see the project here: https://github.com/DivineAlien/laravel-blog

Comment: did u manage to solve this issue? if so please help me out

Comment: use files instead of directories. `(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "routes" .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "web.php" )`. @Milad

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravels default path helpers actually. You dont need to use **DIR** etc. However, it looks like your xampp user does not have a permisson to get data from the folder. You can change chmod 777 to this folder just  to try and lower the numbers for security.

Comment: it's not linux so chmod dosn't work. however i checked full controll box (in windows) but it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you see that one line writes H:/User other H:/Hossein can you try yo use laravel path helpers?

Comment: the path helpers showing orchestra/testbench path not the package path.